# Why do power banks have such a limited amperage vs. 18650 battery packs?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, amperage

*I ordered an LED light that ships without a power supply and has an USB connector to connect one. I thought I'd just buy some power bank subsequently to power the device, but then I realized that*

all the [power banks on the market can only provide like 1-max2.4 amps](http://www.ebay.co.uk/bhp/power-bank). Why can't one find a single one above this limit? The funny thing is that even power banks having 6-8 pieces of 18650 cells are limited to 1-2 amps and I just don't understand why as the C-rate of some 18560 batteries can be so high that some of them could output 10 or even 20 amps, not to mention if you bind 6 or 8 of them together.

*Now it's a pity a cannot buy a good quality power bank to drive [my lamp](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/10000Lm-3x-CREE-XM-L2-T6-LED-Mountain-Bike-Bicycle-Cycle-Light-Front-Lamp-Torch-/351741750349?hash=item51e5712c4d:g:i4EAAOSwNsdXQ8cH) and I have to buy some Chinese 18650 [battery pack](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/3-7V-18650-Rechargeable-Battery-Pack-For-Cree-XML-T6-LED-Bicycle-Light-6400mAh-/321658645981?hash=item4ae4596ddd:g:3yQAAOSwWKtUvgjl) which I don't know how reliable is (and by far less practical for other purposes).. Oh wait, I have a USB connector, so that's not an option either :/*

Comment: I didn't see an amp or power rating in the ebay listing in your link, but the various USB standards themselves limit the current that can (or rather, should) be drawn through a USB socket.

Comment: My answer has been updated to comment on LED requirements (and totally false supplier max lumen claims)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What brhans said is valid IF the lamp is in fact intended for "USB 5 Volt" input but it almost certainly isn't.
Use of a USB connector does not mean it is "USB  5V" operational.
If it was then you MAY be able to parallel connect multiple outlets from some hi power [tm] units. Or not :-).

HOWEVER: the lamp shown says
"...Power Source: 4 x 18650 battery pack (Not Include)..."

Looking at other similar and possibly identical lights [**such as this one**](https://www.amazon.co.uk/KingTop-Lights-Rechargeable-Battery-Waterproof/dp/B00N9U2O2U) shows most specify 4 x 18650 cells arranged 2S2P.

---

You need a spec sheet for the light.
Whether you can get one is TBD.

[Cree XML2 flux binning here](http://www.cree.com/~/media/Files/Cree/LED-Components-and-Modules/XLamp/Data-and-Binning/XLampXML2.pdf).
See page 3 for T6. and
[XML2 data sheet here](http://www.cree.com/~/media/Files/Cree/LED-Components-and-Modules/XLamp/Data-and-Binning/XLampXML2.pdf)

Max current per LED is 3A
For the max flux T6 = cool white
Minimum flux at 3A and about 3.3 Volt  ~= 1000 lumen.
So the whole lamp will produce about 3000 lumen maximum at 9A.
A V_LED ~= 3.3V at 3A and you need some headroom for wiring, regulator etc, you cannot run one at full current on a 1A LiIon cell. You need 2 x LiIon and (hopefully) an efficient buck-regulator.

9A LED current will require about 5A from 2 x 18650 LiIon cells with a decent buck converter.    Needless to say, this is 'rather more' in voltage and current than you will get from any "USB power bank".

Comment: It looks like then I should go with a common 18650 battery pack without any voltage regulator and electronics that would limit the current output, as power banks probably are too week. But first I disassemble the lamp to see whether its LEDs are connected series or parallel to find out how much voltage it needs.

Comment: 160915: Fancy that a downvote after 2+ months to a manifestly useful answer AND the long ago accepted one. I really wonder what's in the minds of such people or if they just like to spread the hate.

Answer (score 6):

Because those 'power banks' with 5V USB outputs are intended to be used to charge things like phones, which are only supposed to draw a limited amount of current.

Also, its more expensive & takes more space to make the 5V regulator circuit for higher currents, so why would the manufacturer's do that when high currents fall outside the intended use case for the device?

The point of having large-capacity batteries in these power banks is to provide larger energy storage capacity over time, not more instantaneous current.